# How to set child`s errno by ptrace?

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

I am trying to intercept and block system calls via ptrace. The problem occurs during the return of the syscall result. errno stays 0, even with -EPERM in the syscall return.

I have tried running this [EXAMPLE](https://github.com/skeeto/ptrace-examples). The result is the same.

```
$ ./xpledge ./example
fread("/dev/urandom")[1] = 0xb2ac39c4
XPledging...
fopen("/dev/urandom")[2]: Success
fread("/dev/urandom")[1] = 0x2e1bd1c4
```

Here's part of the code:

```
if (is_syscall_blocked(regs.orig_rax)) {
  regs.orig_rax = -1; // set to invalid system call
  if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, &regs) == -1)
    FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));
}

/* Run system call and stop on exit */
if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0) == -1)
  FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));
if (waitpid(pid, 0, 0) == -1)
  FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));

switch (regs.orig_rax) {
case -1:
  if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, pid, RAX * 8, -EPERM) == -1)
    FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));
  break;
}
```

So the question is. How to set errno correctly when rejecting a system call?

Comment: Did you read the article linked in the README you linked to? It has at least some pointer how this could be possible.

Comment: @thebusybee Yes, I read the article. I didn't find any solutions there.

Comment: Well, I don't have the time to read that and linked articles, the interesting part seems to be half through. Generally, I don't think that one application can change `errno` of another application, as it is a static variable. If it could, it could change _any_ static variable, and that's a bad thing...

Comment: @thebusybee but ptracer acts as a system call interceptor. how can it return errors? if we step away from ptrace, and call for example openat() with a non-existent file, the kernel will return an error, and set errno to 2. If the kernel can change errno, why can't ptracer?

Comment: I just want to understand where errno comes from. From which registers it is created. Glibc has to handle negative return from syscall(). In glibc documentation I read, quote: "syscall() saves CPU registers before making the system call, restores the registers upon return from the system call, and stores any error returned by the system call in errno(3).". I tried to compile example using musl, but the result is the same. Success in errno, instead of EPERM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the codes in the example do not look correct. In the tutorial there are code pieces which are not same. if you try it, seems it provides the correct output

```
switch (regs.orig_rax) {
    case -1:
        regs.rax = -E2BIG;
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, &regs) == -1)
            FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));
        break;
```